# Issues with vector resizing in C++

Tags: c++, vector

I may be wrong but I was under the impression that the number of elements in a vector in C++ can be altered dynamically? However, when I run the following piece of code I do not get the result I expect.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector <int> vec(10);
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
        vec[i]=i+1;
        cout << vec[i] << endl;
    }
    cout << "the length of this vector is " << vec.size() << endl;
    for(int i=0; i<20; i++){
        vec[i]=i+1;
        cout << vec[i] << endl;
    }
    cout << "the length of this vector is " << vec.size() << endl;
}
```

The output looks like

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
the length of this vector is 10
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
the length of this vector is 10
```

I had expected the second `vec.size()` to give me a value of twenty? I am looking for an object in C++ which behaves something like a list in Python.

Comment: You have to `resize(20)` your vector explicitly. Accessing its elements out-of-bounds is undefined behavior.

Comment: NO, you intialised the vector with a size of 10, to resize either call `resize` or `push_back` to add an element

Comment: If you added a line `vec.resize(20)` before your second loop then it would work

Comment: Thank you, then to the second part, are there any objects in C++ which act like a python list? I have a program in Python to calculate all the pythagorean triplets between two numbers, of course before running the program i can not know how many there are going to be. Hence the need for an object which dynamically changes size.

Comment: With a vector you just call `push_back`, the vector will grow dynamically, depending on your sizes, growing a vector should not be too much of an overhead

Comment: I personally do not worry too much about the container choice so long as it makes logical sense, trying to guess which is better requires profiling but certain containers have performance guarantees which are implementation specific. For small sizes use vector unless you have a good reason logical or performance wise not too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either you should indeed resize the vector using its member function `resize` or add new elements using its member function `push_back`

For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


int main()
{
    const size_t N = 10; 
    std::vector <int> vec( N );

    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        vec[i] = i+1;
        std::cout << vec[i] << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "the length of this vector is " << vec.size() << std::endl;

    vec.resize( 2 * N );

    for ( int i = 0; i < 2 * N; i++ )
    {
        vec[i] = i+1;
        std::cout << vec[i] << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "the length of this vector is " << vec.size() << std::endl;
}
```

Or

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


int main()
{
    const size_t N = 10; 
    std::vector <int> vec( N );

    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        vec[i] = i+1;
        std::cout << vec[i] << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "the length of this vector is " << vec.size() << std::endl;


    for ( int i = N; i < 2 * N; i++ )
    {
        vec.push_back( i+1 );
        std::cout << vec[i] << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "the length of this vector is " << vec.size() << std::endl;
}
```

Take into account that you could use standard algorithm `std::iota` instead of loops.

For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>    

int main()
{
    const size_t N = 10; 
    std::vector <int> vec( N );

    std::iota( v.begin(), v.end(), 1 );

    for ( int x : vec ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cout << "the length of this vector is " << vec.size() << std::endl;

    vec.resize( 2 * N );

    std::iota( v.begin() + N, v.end(), N + 1 );

    for ( int x : vec ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cout << "the length of this vector is " << vec.size() << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To resize a vector you have to call [`resize`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize), accessing elements [out of bound](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at) is undefined behaviour:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector <int> vec(10);
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
        vec[i]=i+1;
        cout << vec[i] << endl;
    }
    cout << "the length of this vector is " << vec.size() << endl;
    // resize here
    vec.resize(20);
    for(int i=0; i<20; i++){
        vec[i]=i+1;
        cout << vec[i] << endl;
    }
    cout << "the length of this vector is " << vec.size() << endl;
}
```

[live example](http://ideone.com/WFjivX)

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `resize()` on your vector. Or call `push_back()` to alter the size.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector <int> vec(10);
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
        vec[i]=i+1;
        cout << vec[i] << endl;
    }
    cout << "the length of this vector is " << vec.size() << endl;
    vec.resize(20); //Added this line
    for(int i=0; i<20; i++){
        vec[i]=i+1;
        cout << vec[i] << endl;
    }
    cout << "the length of this vector is " << vec.size() << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

vector is not intelligent enough to know when do you want to put more stuff in it, so you should either use the `resize` function to extend the size of your vector or the `push_back` function to add a new element each time to the end of the vector.

Answer (score 0):

A `map` will behave more in the way you expect with respect to "arbitrary insertion". But, it is not an array. That is, the elements are not arrange contiguously. But. using the iterators to access its elements, coding wise, you won't notice much of a difference.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int main()
{
    std::map <int, int> vec;
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
        vec[i]=i+1;
        std::cout << vec[i] << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "the length of this vector is " << vec.size() << std::endl;
    for(int i=0; i<20; i++){
        vec[i]=i+1;
        std::cout << vec[i] << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "the length of this vector is " << vec.size() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: a little confusing to use a variable name of `vec` for a `map`

Comment: @EdChum: It depends on the program. A `map` can be used as a sparse vector, so it is not particularly unnatural.

Answer (score 0):

You should write as follows:

```
int main(){ 
   vector <int> vec(10);
   for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
       vec[i]=i+1;
       cout << vec[i] << endl;
   }
   cout << "the length of this vector is " << vec.size() << endl;
   vec.resize(20);
   vec.shrink_to_fit();
   for(int i=0; i<20; i++){ 
    vec[i]=i+1;
    cout << vec[i] << endl;
   }
   cout << "the length of this vector is " << vec.size() << endl;
}
```